# Speed of bullet is different on different device - Unity Mirror

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have a game where it shoots bullets where the user touch the screen. Then I test the game in nox simulator and unity editor. My problem is in the localplayer who fire the bullet has a faster bullet speed compare to other network device which is the unity editor. I didn't use network transform in the bullet only network Identity.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ShootHooks : NetworkBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]private GameObject bulletPrefab;

    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 2f;

    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

    public GameObject hook;

    private GameObject localPlayer;

    public Transform hand;

    Vector3 touch_Pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    public bool isReturnHook = false;

    uint hookNetId;

    private bool isHookMoving = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        GameObject hand = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

        this.CmdInstantiateHook(GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (this.isLocalPlayer)
        {
            while (i < Input.touchCount)
            {
                Touch t = Input.GetTouch(i);
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(t.fingerId))
                    {
                        if (!isHookMoving)
                        {
                            touch_Pos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(t.position);
                            isHookMoving = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            }

            if (isHookMoving)
                CmdMoveHook(hookNetId, touch_Pos);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdMoveHook(uint hookNetID, Vector3 touchPosition)
    {
        if (!isServer)
        {
            GameObject hook = NetworkIdentity.spawned[hookNetID].gameObject;
            hook.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(hook.transform.position, touchPosition, _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            RpcMoveHook(hookNetID, touchPosition);
        }
        
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcMoveHook(uint hookNetID, Vector3 touchPosition)
    {
        GameObject hook = NetworkIdentity.spawned[hookNetID].gameObject;
        hook.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(hook.transform.position, touchPosition, _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    [TargetRpc]
    public void TargetSetUserHook(NetworkConnection target, uint hookNetID)
    {
        hookNetId = hookNetID;
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdInstantiateHook(uint playerNetID)
    {
        hook = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        hook.GetComponent<HookScript>().parentPlayerNetID = playerNetID;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(hook, connectionToClient);

        TargetSetUserHook(connectionToClient, hook.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId);
    }
}
```

I instantiated the bullet on start attach to the player hand.

Comment: There are quite a lot tiny issues/remarks: To begin with don't use `GetTouch` repeatedly .. rather iterate through `Input.touches` which is a lot cheaper. Then sending a command **every frame** is extremly expensive / spams the network so it might be possible that the network reaches a limit and messages get delayed ... which might lead to any other automatic components that syncrhonize the positions of objects get delayed as well since they use the same communication channel as your RPC calls

Comment: Also inside the `[Command]` you already **know** that you have to be the host/server ... so a check for `isServer` is quite redundant

Comment: @derHugo How can I move an object to touch position without using Update or should I replace the update to fixedupdate?

Comment: You should basically do what the NetworkTransform does: Only send position data once in a while (e.g. only every 0.1 units or 0.1 seconds) and then on receiver side `Lerp` towards the last received position in `Update`